# Outlook overlay alignment

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want the rooms to align according overlay at the top of the calendar.
In my current setup I have four calendars from left to right.
Green, Pink, Blue, Orange.

Below, you can see that events are not consistent:
On Monday green goes first, while on Tuesday green goes third.
On Monday pink goes third, on Tuesday pink goes first.

I want them to be in order according at the top panel if possible.
(Monday would be: Test1,Test3,Test4)
(Tuesday would be: Test2,TEst7,test6,test5)

Any suggestions?

[image: Calendar]

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted this and why, but this looks like a valid question. Comments?

Comment: Your title and question refer to 'alignment' but now that I re-read it, you are probably asking about manually setting colors for shared calendars, hence your question is not very clear or useful to others searching this site. If you can edit your question to make it clearer, I'll remove my downvote. If you *are* asking how to assign colors to calendars in Outlook 2010, the answer is to right-click on the calendar tab and then select 'Color' then choose a color.

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick, thanks for your comment. I've edited my question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, that's much clearer thanks - I've removed my downvote. Unfortunately I don't have an answer for you.